# Synchronizing with an object while using the Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a WPF app that from time to time needs to perform a long-running operation - or rather, many small operations that in sum total take a while. I have found that the Task Parallel Library in .Net 4 works fine for this.

However, this operation by nature should run to completion before another of the same kind is started. And there is a very real chance that the user could perform an action that requires the process to run, even while the last one is still going. I would like to synchronize this so that only one is ever running at a time. When the running instance completes, another gains the locks and goes for it, etc. until there are no more of these to run.

I have a class that runs the process named EntityUpdater. In this class I thought it would be clever to define a syncronization object:

```
private static object _lockObject = new object();
```

Making it static should ensure that any EntityUpdater object will await its turn as long as the locking is correct, right?

So my naive first attempt did this before starting the Task (which in turns starts all the other little child tasks, attached to their parent):

```
Monitor.Enter(_lockObject, ref _lockAquired);
```

(_lockAquired is just a local bool)

The main task (the one with all the child tasks) has a continuation, which exists more or less only to do

```
Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
```

I know I should put this in a finally, but it is pretty much the only code in the continuation, so I don't see how that would make a difference.

Anyway, I assume that there is some threading voodoo here that causes me to get the "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code" SynchronizationLockException. I have made sure that _lockAquired is actually true, and I have tried to Monitor.Enter in several different places, but I always get this.

So, basically, my question is how I can synchronize access to an object (the object itself is not important) so that only one copy of the process is running at any given time, and any others that may be started while one is already running will block? The complication - I guess - appears with the added demand that the lock should be released at some time in the future, when all the child tasks of the first TPL Task are complete.

**UPDATE**

Here is some code that shows what I am doing right now.

```
public class EntityUpdater
{
    #region Fields

    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    private bool _lockAquired;

    private Stopwatch stopWatch;

    #endregion

    public void RunProcess(IEnumerable<Action<IEntity>> process, IEnumerable<IEntity> entities)
    {
        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        var processList = process.ToList();

        Monitor.Enter(_lockObject, ref _lockAquired);

        //stopWatch.Start();

        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessTask(processList, entities), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if(_lockAquired)
                Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
            //stopWatch.Stop();

        });
    }

    private void ProcessTask(List<Action<IEntity>> process, IEnumerable<IEntity> entities)
    {

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var switcheroo = entity; // To avoid closure or whatever
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RunSingleEntityProcess(process, switcheroo), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }
    }

    private void RunSingleEntityProcess(List<Action<IEntity>> process, IEntity entity)
    {
        foreach (var step in process)
        {
            step(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is not complicated, and this is also probably far from production worthy - just an attempt that shows what I can't get to work.

The exception I get is of course in the Monitor.Exit() call in the task continuation.

I hope that makes this a bit clearer.

Comment: Sorry, but can you clearify a clearify a bit. It was certainly my impression that no two `lock`ed code blocks using the same object could execute simulteneously, so from what you write everything sounds correct. Perhaps some more code examples would help.

Comment: Hi, sure, I will update with some more source code to show what I am doing.

Comment: The ContinueWith approach is not thread-safe, and unnecessarily complex. Consider a try/finally around a Parallel.ForEach().

Comment: @Henk - Okey, I will try that - however, it was my understanding that the continuation in this case would run after all child tasks are done - and as long as it does little other than actually releasing the lock, could that cause a problem? My main concern is making this easy to call and non-blocking for the caller. Thanks!

Comment: Not a full answer, but be very careful about starting each Task by blocking on acquiring a lock.  If you do this enough times, you can starve the thread pool and all sorts of bad things can happen (for instance, your continuations might not run, because they cannot be scheduled, because other tasks have started up and gone into a blocked state.)  If you don't release until the continuation executes, you're now deadlocked.

Comment: @Dan Bryant - you raise a valid point. That actually seems like another vote in favour of the solution proposed by chibacity below.

Comment: @Dan: Tasks != Threads, and you will not  starve quickly with this. But it could lead to too many Threads and poor performance.

Comment: @Henk, I managed to create deadlock using Tasks while attempting to unit test thread-safety of a class by running multiple instances in parallel.  I had a Barrier and had each instance block at the Barrier until all were complete.  I forget the exact count, but the number of participants required to deadlock the program was in the single digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a queue and ensure that only a single task is executing at a time which will process the queue, e.g.:

```
private readonly object _syncObj = new object();
private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _tasks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

public void QueueTask(Action task)
{
    _tasks.Enqueue(task);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessQueue);
}

private void ProcessQueue()
{
    while (_tasks.Count != 0 && Monitor.TryEnter(_syncObj))
    {
        try
        {
            Action action;

            while (_tasks.TryDequeue(out action))
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_syncObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. That is of course a possibility - but that means that I have to keep track of this class to keep state, right? That is a possibility, but I was trying to avoid that. I will keep it in mind as a possible solution, though!

Comment: @Rune It's best to keep functionality like this separated into their own classes. It's a software engineering practice referred to as "Single Responsibility Principle". In short it's about making your software more modular and easier to understand and maintain. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, yes, I am aware of the principle - thus the EntityUpdater is a separate class, doing only this. However, my point was that I basically want any part of my code to new up a EntityUpdater and start a process, instead of having to locate the single "global" EntityUpdater that has the ConcurrentQueue<T> for the entire system. I would prefer to keep global variables to a minimum if possible. :)

Comment: @Rune You're probably aware of Dependency Injection as well then.

Comment: @chibacity - Absolutely, and I am using it in this app (the "poor man's DI" in this case, as this application does not have very complex needs) as well. However, I would prefer not to keep a singleton around "forever", and rather have the EntityUpdaters be short-lived, transient entities, so the same applies wrt. keeping it a global object.

Comment: @Rune In this case it would make sense for it to be around forever, in a sense it is a service that performs independent background processing. When all tasks have been processed, the tasks evaporate, so it's not as if there is stuff "hanging-around" up to no good :) If you have a need to have things queued from multiple places at any time, it kind of has to work as a service if you want to enforce single task execution or to be precise task serialization.

Comment: @chibacity - That is true, of course. Perhaps it is just an old hangup I have from before managed code. Don't want my object to hang around and be worn down and leak stuff. I see the case for changing my attitude. :)

Comment: @Rune I hear you :) Singletons are more-often-than-not an anti-pattern, but singleton *behavior* supplied via an IoC is quite different. You get the behavior, but you can still vary the implementation. You are very right, global state needs to be well thought out.

Comment: Busy waiting when _tasks.Count == 0 ... the code smells. Instead, put the thread to sleep using Monitor.Wait

Comment: @h9uest when _tasks.Count == 0, the loop is exited. There is no busy waiting.